# When to use Screen, Stage, and Group in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx

I have a main menu screen, which has 4 options, `New Game`, `Load Game`, `Options` and `Exit`.

Then:

`New Game` has more options such as `difficulty`, `# of players` + `Start` button.

`Load Game` has multiple saves to choose from together with `Load` and `Delete` options.

`Options` has `Graphics level` and  `Volume` radio/ slider + `Apply`, `Discard` buttons.

At last, the game screen would have a pannable game window, together with an overlaying UI on the side of the screen.

My problem is, **I don't know what class to use for those UI parts.**

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347297/difference-between-libgdx-stage-and-screen) answer I understand that `Screen` is a full UI page, but it seems that creating a new `Screen` and then a `Stage` for each of those main menu options seems like an overkill, but maybe that's the way to go. I don't know if I should use `Group` and show/hide those depending on what the user clicks. I was also told to use `Table` to lay out the game screen. I'm utterly confused by all the guides I've found online. Every one seems different than the other.

The documentation is really good, but it never states how the individual parts are meant to be integrating with each other.

Is there any consensus on how to use those classes in LibGDX? Or is it a personal preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Screen` is core libGdx part that represents one of many **application screens**, such as a `mainscreen`, a `settingsscreen`, the `gamescreen` and so on.

- mainscreen may contains buttons like settings, play, level that help you to redirect on other screen.
- settingsscreen may contain back button that redirect to previous mainscreen and other ui element like sound button, music button, language selection button.

It is hard to maintain different UI Screen in one `ApplicationListener`context with different required lifecycle.

so there is a `Game` class and `Screen` interface that helps to display one active screen at a time on device screen.

I think you've clear now, why we need different screens.

---

Now how I design one Screen Like MenuSceen that contains menu buttons, game name and similar element that act as HomeScreen.

You can use [scene2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d), a 2D scene graph for building UIs using a hierarchy of actors. Stage and Group are core classes of scene2d.

- `Stage` class has a camera, SpriteBatch, and a root group and handles drawing the actors and distributing input events.
- `Group` class is an actor that may have child actors.