# GameStateManager and screens

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am new to Libgdx and I am not understanding about "states" and "screens".  On my first contact with Libgdx I learned that the main class extends the "Game" class, then creating new classes implementing "Screen", but recently I followed a tutorial using GameStateManager and I think it much more practical and more comfortable using it.  I was wondering if there are any differences between "states" and "screens" and if there are pros and cons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between libgdx Stage and Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347297/difference-between-libgdx-stage-and-screen)

Comment: GameState has nothing to do with a Stage, so no duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 0):

It is seperation of concerns. Read about MVC. Gamestate is part of the model, everything extending screen is part of the View.